# Check if the jQuery page load events fired already

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check if jQuery fired the page load events yet, or do you have to roll your own? I need to alter the behavior of links, but I don't want to wait until the page finishes loading because the user could conceivably click on a link on, say, the top half of the page before the page finishes loading. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
var pageLoaded = false;
$(function() {
  pageLoaded = true;
});

function changeLinks() {
  $("a[data-set-already!='true']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-set-already", "true").click(...);
  }); 
  // Is there something along the lines of jQuery.pageWasLoaded that I can
  // use instead?
  if (!pageLoaded) {
    window.setTimeout(changeLinks, 100);
  }
}
changeLinks(); // Added per @jondavidjohn's question
```

Comment: You can execute javascript inline as a blocking script if you dont want to wait for the page to be ready. As long as you place that script below where jQuery loads.

Comment: have you considered binding the click event with .live()?

Comment: how are you using `changeLinks()`?? in an event?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { });` makes sure the DOM is loaded which is faster than the page loaded.

Comment: @Tejs, that's true, but my pages have hundreds of links, so hundreds of inline scripts doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @Tentonaxe that's clever. Put it in an answer and I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: @PeeHaa, still, I'd like to begin altering the dom before the dom finishes loading. Depending on how your web server flushes html to the client, the client may display some html before the dom finishes loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the document ready shorthand, I'm guessing you mean when the dom is loaded. For this:

```
$.isReady
```

Comment: I want to alter links as soon as they are visible, which may occur before the dom is loaded.

Comment: I get that. $.isReady will be true like pageLoaded in your example once the dom is fully loaded.

Comment: Cool trick.  Not documented though... is this sure to stay around in future versions?

Comment: Not sure, but it is exposed in the same extend statement as noConflict, and I'm sure that is not going away. Furthermore, that it is publicly exposed bodes well for its longevity. They could have just as easily accomplished what they are using it for with a non publicly exposed variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval` and clear the interval on domready:

```
var changeLinksInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $("a[data-set-already!='true']").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("data-set-already", "true").click(...);
    });
}, 100);
$(function () {
    clearInterval(changeLinksInterval);
});
```

By the way, in your code example, you shouldn't need `.each()` - you should be able to call `.attr()` and `.click()` directly and let jQuery do the looping.  Unless there is more to your `.each()` code that you didn't post.

```
$("a[data-set-already!='true']").attr("data-set-already", "true").click(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use .live() to initiate a click event that needs additional work when binding.

```
$("a[data-set-already!='true']").live(function(){
  // since this event will only fire once per anchor tag, you
  // can safely bind click events within it without worrying
  // about getting duplicate bound click events.
  var $this = $(this);
  $this
    .data("dataSetAlready",true)
    .click(myClickHandler);
});
```

this is also a useful technique for late-initializing plugins on elements that may not exist at domReady.

Comment: you could also place your $.each within the live event handler to find similar anchor tags that also dont ahve data set and set them right there, which would be great for late-binding a lightbox plugin to anchor tags.